# How to decide if frailty term needed

Tags: survival, cox-model, heterogeneity, frailty

I´d like to ask the following question:

Is there any sound procedure to test event-history/survival data for unobserved heterogeneity or any indicator that shows that a frailty term should be included? How do you usually decide if inclusion of a frailty term is at stake?
I´m analysing a dataset of 79 countries on a singular, non-recurrent event including both time-varying and time invariant coefficients. My data mostly fulfills the Cox PH model assumptions in terms of linearity and proportionality, however I feel like to make sure that I´m not reporting any heavily biased estimates because of missed frailty.
A second question would then be: Is it possible to implement an individual frailty term in the case of non-recurrent events? I can´t really find a clear statement regarding that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarity your meaning and use of *frailty* metrics.

Answer (score 0):

As a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/vignettes/coxme.pdf) for the R `coxme` package and other references like the [manual page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) for the `frailty()` function in the R `survival` package show, a frailty term in a survival model is the equivalent of a random-effect term in a linear model. So think about them in the same way. They are used to capture correlation structures within the data.

If there's only 1 observation per case, then there is no within-case correlation to capture. In survival models, the observation is effectively the event time and the covariate values at that time. So without recurring events you can't distinguish a case-specific frailty. That would be like trying to specify random intercepts when you only have one observation per case in a linear model.

For your dataset of 79 countries you will have to apply your knowledge of the subject matter to decide how to proceed. Are there geographical, economic, demographic, political, or other characteristics of groups of countries that might lead to differences in the time to event? If so, are those best modeled as fixed effects or as random/frailty effects? The decision-making process is pretty similar: random/frailty effects gain from partial pooling among cases and cut down on the number of degrees of freedom lost in the model, but they might not always be as useful as fixed effects if there aren't many different groups to start with, as the random/frailty term imposes a specific distribution of the random effects.